# No hyphenation patterns (spanish)

Tags: hyphenation, spanish

Hyphenation in my Spanish latex document is not accurate to language rules. Searching in the log I founded:

```
ackage babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language 'Spanish' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 51.
```

I tried reinstalling babel-spanish and hyphen-spanish (`sudo tlmgr install --reinstall hyphen-spanish babel-spanish`), but it didn't work. The output was:

```
[1/3, ??:??/??:??] reinstall: babel-spanish [217k]
[2/3, 00:01/00:03] reinstall: hyph-utf8 [312k]
[3/3, 00:02/00:02] reinstall: hyphen-spanish [150k]
running mktexlsr ...
done running mktexlsr.
regenerating language.dat
regenerating language.def
regenerating language.dat.lua
running fmtutil-sys --byhyphen "/var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.dat" --no-error-if-no-engine=luametatex,luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/v7tnXUUqEh/029NhNE0MO ...
running fmtutil-sys --byhyphen "/var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.def" --no-error-if-no-engine=luametatex,luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/v7tnXUUqEh/029NhNE0MO ...
running fmtutil-sys --byhyphen "/var/lib/texmf/tex/generic/config/language.dat.lua" --no-error-if-no-engine=luametatex,luajithbtex,luajittex,mfluajit --status-file=/tmp/v7tnXUUqEh/029NhNE0MO ...
tlmgr: package log updated: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/tlmgr.log
tlmgr: command log updated: /var/lib/texmf/web2c/tlmgr-commands.log
```

Checked the file language.dat, and it has the Spanish hyphen uncommented. Also tried to do `sudo fmtutil-sys --all` and it returns the following:

```
fmtutil [INFO]: disabled formats: 3
fmtutil [INFO]: successfully rebuilt formats: 27
fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 25 (euptex/euptex eptex/eptex eptex/ptex pdftex/utf8mex pdftex/mltex euptex/uptex luatex/luacsplain pdftex/xmltex euptex/uplatex pdftex/jadetex pdftex/pdfmex pdftex/pdfjadetex euptex/platex pdftex/pdfxmltex euptex/platex-dev xetex/xelatex pdftex/eplain hitex/hilatex euptex/uplatex-dev pdftex/mex pdftex/csplain pdftex/pdflatex xetex/pdfcsplain pdftex/pdfcsplain luatex/pdfcsplain)
fmtutil [INFO]: total formats: 55
fmtutil [INFO]: exiting with status 25
```

After all this step, the error persists. How can I solve this and allow a proper hyphenation?

Edit: MWE (text was copied from a Wikipedia article):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel} % pone el idioma en español

\begin{document}

El artículo, en morfología lingüística, es un tipo de determinante actualizador, una categoría morfológica que emplean algunas lenguas para actualizar o precisar la referencia de un sustantivo, transformándolo de desconocido y abstracto («un libro») a conocido y concreto («el libro»). Es un indicador que sitúa lo que se dice en el contexto común al que lo dice y al que lo oye, o sea, en el mutuo acuerdo de los interlocutores.

\end{document}
```

Log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.11.8)  8 NOV 2023 13:14
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**texstudio_SIMMDH.tex
(./texstudio_SIMMDH.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2021/02/14 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks17
\inpenc@posthook=\toks18
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2023/08/29 v3.93 The Babel package
\babel@savecnt=\count193
\U@D=\dimen141
\l@unhyphenated=\language3

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
\bbl@dirlevel=\count194

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf
Language: spanish.ldf 2021/05/27 v5.0q Spanish support from the babel system


Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language 'Spanish' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for \language=0 instead on input line 51.

Package babel Info: Hyphen rules for 'spanish' set to \l@english
(babel)             (\language0). Reported on input line 52.
\es@quottoks=\toks19
\es@quotdepth=\count195
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 570.
Package babel Info: Making . an active character on input line 675.
Package babel Info: Making < an active character on input line 722.
Package babel Info: Making > an active character on input line 722.
)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/locale/es/babel-spanish.tex
Package babel Info: Importing font and identification data for spanish
(babel)             from babel-es.ini. Reported on input line 11.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count196
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
)
(/home/jose-tomas/.cache/texstudio/archivos-temporales/texstudio_SIMMDH.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 8.
)
\openout1 = `texstudio_SIMMDH.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 6.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 8.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 8.

[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(/home/jose-tomas/.cache/texstudio/archivos-temporales/texstudio_SIMMDH.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 8.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 8.
)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-29>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1909 strings out of 476894
 33574 string characters out of 5809852
 1920807 words of memory out of 5000000
 23255 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 560805 words of font info for 45 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 45i,5n,52p,484b,365s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/t
exmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb>
Output written on /home/jose-tomas/.cache/texstudio/archivos-temporales/texstud
io_SIMMDH.pdf (1 page, 24054 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 18 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

[image]

Comment: your warning shows `Spanish` with a capital S, did you get that from the document you posted (if you add `\stop` so it finishes?

Comment: your log shows that pdftex/pdflatex  failed to build, the log for that would give some more information why it failed

Comment: Do you have more than one TeX system on your device? If so, some packages may be installed in one place, some installed in another place, and the binary programs are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated the code and included the log content. Yes, it shows Spanish with capital S. It doesn't fail to build. The hyphenation is just a warning.

Comment: your pdflatex _format_ failed to build (as shown in the `fmtutil [INFO]: failed to build: 25 ` line you posted. so the log of the generation of the format will show errors (not the log of the current document)

Comment: @rallg I don't have multiples TeX system, but I have some folders from previews versions of latex. I must do --reinstall with tlmgr, but I haven't got any problem with other packages. Also tried to manually move the files to the hyphenation folder of the currently used latex folder, without good luck.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh sorry, I see. I will try to found a solution for this.

Comment: " Also tried to manually move the files to the hyphenation folder of the currently used latex folder, without good luck" don't do that!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there a way to do a cleanup of the latex packages and folder? I think older installation are in conflict with my actual TeX installation. I'm trying to update with "sudo tlmgr update --all", and it shows a lot of error of missing packages files.

Comment: if you installed the new tex correctly older installations have no effect (I have several tex installations on this machine and can set the path to choose which to use)

Comment: Your document shows `TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)` that is the linux system tex not a tex you installed from tug and it should not be updated via `tlmgr` you should update it using your linux package manager (apt or yum ot rpm or whatever arch linux uses)

Comment: do not use `tlmgr` at all. Use your linux package manager to install this https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-langspanish/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the help, after clean installation and langspanish, it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a clean installation of TeX Live, and installing all necessary packages via Arch Linux packages and not tlmgr (including https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-langspanish/, as @DavidCarlisle suggested) now hyphenation work as intended.